# Access private pages from external Laravel website

Tags: laravel, authentication, single-sign-on, laravel-passport

I need to find a way to give access to some private pages of our Laravel 5 website from the websites of some customers of us. Example: I am on logged a customer-of-us website and I should be able to click and open a link to a private page of our web application. Ideally, there would be no front-end pop-up asking for granting access.

Obviously I want our private pages to remain private for anybody else than these given clients and I want to do that the safest possible way (I could check the http_referer for example but that would be very very insecure).

It seems that Passport is the right tool to achieve that but I really don't know where to start.

Could you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume the customer already has to be signed in to the website?

Comment: Yes, that is right!

Comment: Why not just add a table to your database and then run a middleware to check if user has been granted access